# Would a US marine teleported in the Cretaceous be able to survive a T-rex attack

Tags: time-travel, dinosaurs

A US marine fighting in the Middle East inadvertently falls in a hole that happens to be a time portal and is teleported in the Cretaceous era, 70 million years in the past.

Our Marine is equipped with a M16A4 and the standard Marine equipment (grenades, binoculars etc...).

When wakes up, he is in an open forest, unharmed. A T-Rex wandering nearby unfortunately spots him and decides to have a bite from this strange looking monkey.

Does our poor Marine stand a chance? Can he somehow scare off or even kill the T-Rex with his weapons?

Comment: Usually, I'd say it's pretty much opinion based, since I know nobody who has tested a T-Rex endurance to modern fire power, and it hinges on the narrator bias... But since we're on WB.SE, I'm waiting here to see a full expose about why or why not this is going to work...

Comment: Since the human may have little resistance to the microbes of the era, he may prefer the quick death from the T-Rex.

Comment: Since this really depends on how smart your marine is in their response to the predator rather than any equipment they may be carrying you're in plot territory not Worldbuilding.

Comment: @user535733 Since the Cretaceous is roughly sixty million years before humans evolved, microbes won't have had the chance to adapt to infecting humans. The tyrannosaur is worth worrying about, he can forget quick death by the sniffles.

Comment: @a4android I'd love to see a microbiologist's or virologist's take on that. Not all bacteria and viruses are all that picky (rabies attacks just about any mammal, for instance). Humans were just a gleam in God's eye, but mammals had been around for well over 100M years at that point so something would have evolved to prey on them. Even if there weren't mammal-specific microbes that found a human "good enough," I wouldn't be surprised if there were a fungus that quite liked some warm moist bit of the human body, for instance, which his body didn't know how to fight off... :-)

Comment: I'd say we can agree that the death rate of T-Rexs by M16 is 0.00%, so it's not that effective, no? On the other hand, also the death rate of humans by T-Rex is 0.00%, so the marine is pretty safe. Isn't he?

Comment: There seems a far greater chance of the biosphere being at risk from the human's pathogens than the other way around. Partly because it's a numbers game (only one human, zillions of things for him to infect), partly because we have inherited defenses against historical pathogens. But I'm no pathogenologist.

Comment: First of all, I think you should look into exactly what the equipment load of a Marine would be at the time that the action is taking place. Second, there's no way that the personal rifle carried by pretty much any infantryman in the world is going to stop a charging TRex. You need to think .50 cal sniper rifles, grenade launchers, and anti-tank recoilless rifles. And don't forget that said marine would likely not have much in the way of food or ammo on him when he lands in a time and place wholly unsuitable to the survival of a human being.

Comment: While I'd debate "off topic", this seems largely a duplicate of https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/134962/how-feasible-is-a-man-portable-firearm-capable-of-incapacitating-a-large-dinosau - one answer argues "you could quite likely do so with a standard assault rifle (7.62mm), with good placement, as the skull of the T-Rex at least, and probably a good many other dinos, is full of holes, and so shots could be fired into the creature's brain without having to contend with bone." and another convincingly argues that the knees are excellent weak spots.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for making good points. The majority of human diseases are adapted to our species. There are many microbes that cross species, but those species need to be in close contact with each other. Fungi & yeasts certainly can infect a human. i discounted fungi as microbes, but they could be a possible problem in the Cretaceous. It's a balance of risk factors. T-Rex is the biggie, death by microbes only if he's lucky. Thanks for your good comment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Yes.

Once upon a time, big game hunters went after elephants with [elephant guns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant_gun), large-caliber rifles like the the .450 Nitro Express.

These days, poachers kill elephants with [assault rifles](https://news.nationalgeographic.com/2016/01/160112-Africa-gun-control-poaching-elephants-rhinos/), just like the rifle your Marine would carry.

The open forest should allow the Marine fire at a decent range. In close jungle, it might become a mutual kill with the T Rex bleeding out only after he killed the Marine.

Comment: "Can a T-Rex be killed by an assault rifle?" is a rather different question than "Could the Marine kill the T-Rex before the T-Rex killed him?"

Comment: A National Geographic ad for gun control doesn't say a small-caliber "assault rifle" is the right choice for big-game hunting. Fire enough rounds, and sure, it will take down a large animal -- but if you're defending yourself, you want that animal taken down FAST. A 5.56mm round like the one fired by the M16A4 isn't going to do it -- there are anecdotal reports of it not being able to stop people, let alone elephants or a T-Rex.

Comment: W.D.M. "Karamojo" Bell is reported to have killed over 1,000 elephants (for the record, don't shoot elephants) with a 7x57mm Mauser, nobody's idea of an elephant gun. He was a good shot and knew the elephant's anatomy very well. However, that round has about twice the muzzle energy of the 5.56, a T. Rex is about twice the size of an African elephant, Bell was not defending himself against an "attack" but choosing his shots at leisure, and our Marine couldn't possibly have Bell's knowledge of his quarry's anatomy. As for "decent range", energy falls off at range. I don't buy it.

Comment: I'm also dubious about the 5.56 NATO round being able to kill the T Rex fast enough.  To survive a charge I think the Marine would need to have an [M203 40mm grenade launcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M203_grenade_launcher) attached to his M4, and be far enough away to safely use it to take down a charging TRex.

Comment: If you want anything remotely plausible, make him a failed paleontology grad student who joined the marines, and make him a Designated Marksman with a .308. Maybe "plausible" isn't the exact word I'm looking for, but it's SF after all.

Comment: @DanNeely I love that you called it an M4 (I don't remember a single person in Iraq having a A4 that wasn't supply or a cook or something). We all had the carbines (M4 or HKs), SAM-Rs or SDM-Rs (now retired, I think), SAWs, and a very few lucky ones had Mk12s. So when I read the question I saw it as - "oh, a non-combat MOS Marine with only boot camp & MTC training to fallback on using an old weapon"

Comment: You clearly know very little about guns and ammunition loads. Hence the use of the term "assault rifle" ... no such thing, except in video games. Even a fully automatic combat rifle chambered in 5.56 would be utterly inadequate in taking down something the size of a T-Rex. The first 30 rounds would simply piss it off, and by the time you'd reload, it would be biting you in half. To put things in perspective, I wouldn't feel entirely comfortable hunting _bears_ with 5.56, because the round is simply not powerful enough to take one down before it has the chance to rush you.

Comment: @JGreenwell meanwhile I just assumed the asker wasn't aware that the m4 had largely replaced the m16 in actual service; but didn't think it was worth an explicit callout.

Comment: @AndreiROM 5.56 It would be a poor choice for hunting a bear because you want a quick/clean kill; but bears are generally not aggressive enough to continue an attack after being shot, so even much lower power handgun rounds are adequate for self defense.  If a t-rex would break of the attack like a bear after getting hit, or charge down the length of the spear impaling it to kill you with its dying breath like a boar (boar spears have strong crossbars to stop this) is up to the author.  https://www.ammoland.com/2018/02/defense-against-bears-with-pistols-97-success-rate-37-incidents-by-caliber/

Comment: @danneely - having read the article, my position hasn't changed. The the most important factors in defending against a bear are *1)* Shot placement *2)* Firepower, and *3)* (if all else fails) How determined the animal is to get you. Sure, 9mm will kill a bear, if you get it in the heart / lungs, but even mortally wounded might it still have enough time to severely maul you? Emphatically, yes. Similarly, 5.56 is excellent if you get a good shot in, but if you miss the main organs by even a little bit, that round will not do enough damage in the entry area to take down the animal.

Comment: @AndreiROM I think you need to read more closely.  While some encounters were well placed shots that quickly killed the bear,a number of them only inflicted wounds minor enough the bears body wasn't found (and thus presumably survived).  And since this was every documented encounter the author could find, it's not reasonable to assume they were all steely eyed marksmen taking careful aim and not people panicked and blazing away in the bears general direction until it ran off or they shot dry.

Comment: @danneely - I did read very closely, hence point #3. However, you can't count on the fact that the bear that charges you will be easily dissuaded, hence you plan for one that isn't, in which case you pack a load that will penetrate better, and do the most damage possible, while still being manageable.

Comment: @RobCrawford, this isn't about finding the best weapon to hunt Tyrannosaurs, the question is how long a Tyrannosaur will live after someone emptied a magazine of 5.56mm NATO into it, and how well it will fight before dying.

Comment: @AndreiROM "assault rifle" is a very common descriptor for a select fire rifle that utilizes a detachable magazine and intermediate rounds (e.g. 5.56x45mm or 7.62x39mm).  Not sure where you got the idea that there's no such thing as an assault rifle.

Comment: @DanNeely I only do because it changes the training and equipment the Marine would likely have.

Comment: @AndreiROM https://www.heckler-koch.com/en/products/military/assault-rifles.html The people at HK sure think it's a thing. So does everybody else.

Answer (score 11):

**Yes**

T-rex are animals not movie monsters. Once something starts causing them pain they will leave. Humans use rocks to drive lions away, bullets will drive it away if they don't kill it outright. Large predators are usually wary of things they do not recognize anyway. A predator that routinely gets injured while procuring a meal is not going to have many offspring. Herbivores are different, and a lot more dangerous.

Animals only attack with little concern for injury when directly threatened. Getting yourself killed trying to procure lunch is not beneficial. To quote an old saying Why does the rabbit run faster than the fox, (or in this case fight harder) the fox is only running for its lunch the rabbit is running for its life.

Comment: It's really worth mentioning predators stay alive by preying on the weak, not tussling with what is portrayed as a threat. Little things making loud noises come to mind, or even cats being chased by large, angry rats.

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that a predator of the size of a T-Rex would see the human as a very small meal - adding to the "not worth it" factor

Comment: Also standard Maine equipment includes [flashbangs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M84_stun_grenade) which would also be a helpful way to scare away a predator re: @lucasgcb "loud noises" comment (nice thought there).

Comment: This was my first thought as well, but we do need to consider that there are some animals which are more stubborn. I saw a video of a rhino that kept charging a group in which one member was continually shooting it. The rhino did not stop until it was almost upon them and another member gave it one shot with a much higher powered gun which dropped it dead.

Comment: @Aaron Rhinos are not predators and if they are attacking they are stressed and fending a threat off their space rather than pure self-preserving. Hippos are also not predatory but still are incredibly violent and unrelenting when it comes to having their space invaded. Assuming a T-Rex doesn't have a tiny brain like herbivores, our marine will ironically have a harder time with everything else that does.

Comment: @Aaron Rhinos and Hippo are fighting for self preservation not a meal, that is a big difference in cost vs benefit. Attacking a direct threat will little concern for injury can be beneficial. Getting yourself killed trying to procure lunch is not.  This is why herbivores are often more dangerous than predators.

Comment: @John I thought your comment added nicely to your answer and edited it in. Feel free to undo if you disagree.

Answer (score 6):

Well, your soldier couldn't outrun it and probably couldn't easily duck attacks, either. Recent models suggest running speeds of 27 km/h), and other [recent studies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyrannosaurus#Speed) hypothesize that Tyrannosaurus was capable of making relatively quick turns and could likely pivot its body more quickly when close to its prey, or that while turning, the theropod could "pirouette" on a single planted foot while the alternating leg was held out in a suspended swing during pursuit.

I doubt, however, that a T-rex could survive a sustained burst from an assault rifle. Chugging a grenade down its throat should also do the trick, and the dinosaur might even reflexively swallow anything entering its mouth.

All this is necessarily speculative, since we have never studued a T-rex in the wild.

Comment: I'm curious, how do you suggest to chug a grenade down a T-Rex throat? :)

Comment: I saw opposite evidence to this, actually! - that T-Rexes wouldn't be able to run nowhere near the speed needed to grab a regular person!

Comment: [More details here](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/speaking-of-science/wp/2017/07/19/tyrannosaurus-rex-couldnt-run-but-it-was-a-speedy-walker/?noredirect=on&utm_term=.2f0221fe8e71)

Comment: @Nyakouai If the T-Rex has it's mouth open, throw it?

Comment: *"I doubt, however, that a T-rex could survive a sustained burst from an assault rifle"* -- can you share your calculations? A T Rex is a very large animal (~9,000 kg), and there's some debate about whether the 5.56 round is adequate to humanely take whitetail deer (~68kg). And remember that this is an "attack", not calmly sniping at an unsuspecting animal. If it bleeds out nine hours after it eats you, maybe that counts as a tie, but who do you brag to? And how?

Comment: Correction: ~5,000 kg.

Comment: The deer example is one bullet, not a burst. And you don't have to kill the T-rex right away if the hurt slows it down enough or makes it choose a different meal.

Comment: Two order of magnitude, Klaus.

Answer (score 0):

**Signs point to 'No.'**

[Recently a British soldier, fully kitted out for anti-poaching operations, was killed by an elephant](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-48190628).  A T-Rex is quite a bit larger, and carnivorous besides.

Even if they manage to kill the dinosaur, they're still on their own in very foreign lands.  Almost any wound is going to drastically reduce our soldier's life expectancy.

Of course, it's much less-surprising to encounter an elephant during anti-elephant-poaching mission than it is to encounter a T-Rex after waking up.

Comment: In that article, the soldier was there to protect the elephants.  They accidentally startled some elephants and one charged.  Did the soldier discharge his weapon or try to avoid the charging elephant?  I don't think you can directly compare the two scenarios without knowing if the soldier fired or not.